# How to reset input value with PrimeNG

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I have encountered one problem. I am trying to reset the input value, when I unclick it but it does not work with PrimeNG . I have tried @ViewChild decorator but it did not work.
Could someone tell me how can I reset written value when I unclick my input field?

```
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="brand" [suggestions]="filteredBrands" (completeMethod)="filterBrands($event)" [size]="30"
[minLength]="1" placeholder="Hint: type 'v' or 'f'" [dropdown]="true">
<ng-template let-brand pTemplate="item">
    <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
        <div style="font-size:18px;margin:10px 10px 0 0">{{brand}}</div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MenuItem} from 'primeng/api';
import {SelectItem} from 'primeng/api';
import {SelectItemGroup} from 'primeng/api';
import { CountryService } from './countryservice';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  providers: [CountryService]
})
export class AppComponent { 

brands: string[] = ['Audi','BMW','Fiat','Ford','Honda','Jaguar','Mercedes','Renault','Volvo','VW'];

filteredBrands: any[];

brand: string;

constructor(private countryService: CountryService) { }
    
filterBrands(event) {
    this.filteredBrands = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < this.brands.length; i++) {
        let brand = this.brands[i];
        if (brand.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.query.toLowerCase()) == 0) {
            this.filteredBrands.push(brand);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Thank you.

[enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-autocomplete-demo-xzzlma?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: what do you mean by unclick? On blur you mean?

Comment: exactly. but the OnBlur method did not work

Comment: so even if certain value is selected and you click outside you mean it should get empty? Like Volvo is selected and you click outside the input field, it gets empty?

Comment: I mean when i text something for example "vo" to find volvo and I click somewhere else, the "vo" word is still there. It does not reset

Comment: But onBlur will apply to whenever you click outside, even if value is selected. Because that's the behavior of it. Your requirement is if nothing is selected then empty it something right? Not if a valid value is selected

Answer (score 0):

So you can set brand to empty string. `(onBlur)` set your `brand = ''` Like Following:

On you html file p-autocomplete add this `(onBlur)="check()"`. You could directly set the brand to empty string but it will happen always when you click outside. so a check function that will see in your array if it finds the string inside it, if its true it will not clear else it will. Here is the ts code `check()` function:

```
check() {
  if(this.brands.indexOf(this.brand) != -1) {
    console.log('inside if, found',this.brand);
  } else {
    console.log('not found');
    this.brand = '';
  }
}
```

This is working perfectly, just one caveat is that you will feel slight snapping after selection because while selecting value it is onBlur as well.

Comment: You are welcome. :) Kindly set it as accepted answer and vote so if anyone comes across similar scenario it can be helpful for them.